# function to test if strings identical up to position x

Tags: r

Is there a function to test if two strings are identical up to a specific position? Or maybe to get the identical part and the differing part back.

I was searching some string functions and could not find a ready to use function. But I expected that this is a common use.

I expect something like:

```
a <- stringDiff('difference_MSA_vs_DFI', 'difference_SEL_vs_BLA')
print(a)
$identical
[1] "difference_"

$differing
[1] "MSA_vs_DFI" "SEL_vs_BLA"
```

Comment: What would you like the result to be if the strings where like this: `stringDiff('MSA_vs_DFI_difference', 'SEL_vs_BLA_difference')`

Comment: I think the @dimitris_ps made a good point.  If the first position is not matching, then the whole string will be in the `differing` category

Comment: what would be the result of comparing `my_dog_is_here` and `doggy_style` ?

Comment: My original purpose was searching for all columns in a data frame which match the regex '^difference' and afterwards I want to use the matching columns in a shiny app to select only the experiments 'MSA_vs_DFI' or 'SEL_vs_BLA'. I know, I can create a little function on my own. I was just confused that something like this does not exists as a function. And my result was just a suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a ready made function that does this. This homemade one sort of works: Its probably not very efficient and only works with 2 strings. But maybe enough for your purpose:

```
stringDiff <- function(strings){
    string_by_letter = strsplit(strings, split = '')
    i_diff = which(string_by_letter[[1]] != string_by_letter[[2]])

    list(identical = substr(strings[1], 1, min(i_diff) - 1),
        differing = substr(strings, min(i_diff) , stop = 1000000L))
        }

stringDiff(strings =  c('difference_MSA_vs_DFI', 'difference_SEL_vs_BLA'))

$identical
[1] "difference_"

$differing
[1] "MSA_vs_DFI" "SEL_vs_BLA"
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by writing a custom function. The function below works correctly for the case you provided and for more special cases such as:

- input strings x and y of different lengths: there are no unnecessary warnings displayed in that case.
- input strings x and y are the same
- one of the input strings is empty

.

```
stringDiff <- function(x,y)
{
  xylen <- min( nchar(x), nchar(y) )

  xcut <- substr(x,1,xylen)
  ycut <- substr(y,1,xylen)

  idx_array <- which( 
    (strsplit(xcut,split="")[[1]] == strsplit(ycut,split="")[[1]]) == FALSE 
  )

  idx <- ifelse( length(idx_array)==0, xylen+1, idx_array[1])

  list(identical=substr(x,1,idx-1),
          differing=c(substr(x,idx,nchar(x)), 
                      substr(y,idx,nchar(y))
                      )
  )
}

stringDiff(x='difference_MSA_vs_DFI', y='difference_SEL_vs_BLA')
```

The result is:

```
$identical
[1] "difference_"

$differing
[1] "MSA_vs_DFI" "SEL_vs_BLA"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using partial matching in a loop (pmatch). It is matching the string incrementally and puts it in a new vector "outcome" up to the point that there is a mismatch.

```
A<-c("difference_MSA_vs_DFI")
B<-c("difference_SEL_vs_BLA")

part<-NULL
outcome<-NULL
res<-NULL

for(i in 1:nchar(B)){
part<-substr(A, 1, i)
res<-pmatch(part,B, nomatch=FALSE)
if (res=="1") outcome<-part
}
print(outcome)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be one not very nice looking solution. it works for a vector of strings:

```
stringDiff <- function(string_vector){

   # The concept is to split the strings by letter 
   # and compare each character at every position.

  temp <- strsplit(string_vector, "*")

  position <- sum(cumsum(sapply(1:(max(sapply(temp, function(x) length(x)))), function(y){
    length(unique(sapply(temp, function(z){z[y]})))-1
  }))==0)

  identical=substr(string_vector[1], 1, position)

  differing =gsub(identical,  "", string_vector)
  return(list(identical=identical, differing=differing))
}
```

As an example:

```
a <- c('difference_MSA_vs_DFI', 'difference_SEL_vs_BLA', 'difference_XEL_vs_BLA')

stringDiff(a)

$identical
[1] "difference_"

$differing
[1] "MSA_vs_DFI" "SEL_vs_BLA" "XEL_vs_BLA"
```